# Assign value to variable using multiple conditional statement

Tags: php

How can I simplify this:

```
if($quantity == 0)
   $basket_item['status_text'] = 'out of stock';

else if($quantity >= $requested)
   $basket_item['status_text'] = 'available';

else if($quantity < $requested)
   $basket_item['status_text'] = 'not enough in stock';
```

As you can see I have to keep defining the `$basket_item['status_text']` variable each time.

EDIT: just fixed the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `function` as below

```
function defineStatus($quantity,$requested) {
   if($quantity == 0)
     return 'out of stock';

   else if($quantity >= $requested)
     return 'available';

   else if($quantity < $requested)
     return 'not enough in stock';
}
```

Now Call function where you want to take this status decision.

```
$basket_item['status_text'] = defineStatus($quantity,$requested);
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't realize it. I will take care next time

Comment: Please do; edit reviewers are supposed to pay attention to what the edit changes. Blatant spam like that should *never* be approved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Just do it: `if($quantity == 0 || $quantity < $requested)`

Your code will look like:

```
if($quantity == 0 || $quantity < $requested)
   $status_text = 'not in stock';
   // $basket_item['status_text'] = 'not in stock';

else if($quantity >= $requested)
   $status_text = 'available';
```

I've commented a line, that's because i guess you're using only `$status_text` variable, but not using the another.